# SQLite on android stop unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am on sqlite android. When Run project, I got some troubles. 
I have 2 things. The  VivsHelper is the former and MainActivity is the latter.Here is my code:
class VivzHelper:

```
public class VivzHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vivzdatabase";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "VIVZTABLE";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String UID = "_id";
private static final String NAME = "_Name";
private Context context;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME +" ("+ UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +NAME+"_Name VARCHAR(255));";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " IF EXISTS";
public VivzHelper(Context context){
    super(context, "", null, 1);
    this.context = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Oncreate called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    VivzHelper vivzHelper;
    vivzHelper = new VivzHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = vivzHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

When I Run, my application stopped unexpedtedly. why is that? help me

Here is log cat:

```
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535): java.lang.RuntimeException:    Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlitefull/com.example.sqlitefull.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1579)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:539)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.example.sqlitefull.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-06 23:48:39.736: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post stack trace

Comment: Hey An Thuy Dinh,i think the Constructor `super(context, "", null, 1);` should be like this `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, as @Shifar was saying, the args for the super class are invalid, you must pass a database name! Also check you Create statement, you got the name "+NAME+"_Name VARCHAR(255));" in it and a semicolon